# Meta tag not working for mobile Freindly website

Tags: seo

from 21 April google launch Mobile Freindly website algorithm. I used the meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"  Tag but its not working . what i should do now for this.

Answer (score 0):

The release you are referring to by Google on the 21st of April is a push to get site owners to make mobile friendly versions of their websites.  Simply by placing viewport markup into your website does not make it mobile friendly, the design needs to respond to the resolution of the device you are viewing the website in.  Recommend looking more into "Responsive Website Design".  If your site is too big to do a redesign before the 21st, consider making an m.yourdomain.com mobile version of your site while you work on a redesign to responsive.

To check if your website will pass the mobile friendly test by using Google Webmaster Tools Mobile Friendly checker tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Hope this helps.